# Write a python function to return a differential equation: cannot assign to operator?

Tags: python, ode

I would like to write a Python function which simply returns a differential equation. Basically, my ODE is a function of wind speed, solar insolation and ambient temperature. I want this first function to take in those values and to produce an equation; I then want to take multiple such equations and solve them simultaneously, but I was hoping to set each equation in a separate function, as below.

```
def define_front_equation(wind_speed,  insolation,  ambient_temperature):
    sky_temperature = 0.0552*ambient_temperature**(1.5)
    param_heat = tau_alpha_param*area_measurement_for_everything*insolation 
    front_convection = convection_param*area_measurement_for_everything*(TempF - ambient_temperature)
    front_radiation1 =  radiation_param*glass_emissivity*view_factor*area_measurement_for_everything
    front_radiation2 = (TempF**4) - ambient_temperature**4
    front_radiation = front_radiation1*front_radiation2
    dTempF/dt = (param_Ps + param_heat - front_convection - front_radiation)*(1/glass_mass)
    return dTempF/dt
```

The third to last line gives me the syntax error "cannot assign to operator". Am I doing something wrong here? How do I get around this?

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: What were you expecting that assignment to `dTempF/dt` to do?  Were you expecting that to be interpreted as a single variable name?  Or were you expecting `dTempF` and `dt` to be separately assigned (and if so, to what values)?

Comment: Use a variable name like `dTempF_dt`

Comment: Where is the input `TempF` that would be used to define its incremental change? Is that meant to be a function generator, returning a co-routine or a lambda expression (also a co-routine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably coming from `dTempF/dt`. In Python, variable names have certain rules, namely, that they can only contain letters, numbers, or underscores and must start with a letter (or underscore). Python is interpreting "/" as the division operator. Use `dTempF_dt` instead.

Comment: This is a guess at best based on incomplete information in the question. This is best suited to a comment that requests clarification.

Comment: By probably I mean 99.99%. I think it is fairly clear where the error is coming from.